# how to get user email address using Parse Facebook for Android-

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I am trying to get email address of user from ParseFacebook for android but i am getting null when i try to fetch email.
here is my code

```
//on Login:

List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("email","basic_info", "user_about_me", "user_location");
        ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(permissions,SignUpActivity. this, new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                SignUpActivity.this.progressDialog.dismiss();
                if(err!=null)
                Log.w("parse exception",""+err.getMessage());
                if (user == null) {
                Log.e("FB","Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                } else if (user.isNew()) {
                    Log.w("FB","User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                    //showUserDetailsActivity();
                    getProfileInfo();
                } else {
                    Log.w("FB","User logged in through Facebook!");
                //  showUserDetailsActivity();
                    getProfileInfo();
                }
            }

        });
```

making request:

```
Request request = Request.newMeRequest(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(),new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            JSONObject userProfile = new JSONObject();
                            try {
                                // Populate the JSON object
                                try {
                                    userProfile.put("facebookId", user.getId());
                                    userProfile.put("name", user.getName());
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    // TODO: handle exception
                                }
                                if (user.getProperty("email") != null) {
                                    userProfile.put("email",(String) user.getProperty("email"));
                                }
                                if (user.getLocation().getProperty("name") != null) {
                                    userProfile.put("location", (String) user.getLocation().getProperty("name"));
                                }
                                if (user.getProperty("gender") != null) {
                                    userProfile.put("gender",(String) user.getProperty("gender"));
                                }


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e("Facebook parsing data","Error parsing returned user data.");
                            }

                        } else if (response.getError() != null) {
                            if ((response.getError().getCategory() == FacebookRequestError.Category.AUTHENTICATION_RETRY) || (response.getError().getCategory() == FacebookRequestError.Category.AUTHENTICATION_REOPEN_SESSION)) {
                                Log.e("Facebook parsing data","The facebook session was invalidated.");
                                //onLogoutButtonClicked();
                            } else {
                                Log.e("Facebook parsing data","Some other error: "+ response.getError().getErrorMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        request.executeAsync();
```

I have tried everything but where ever i do i am getting email null :(

Answer (score 0):

After setting the permissions as above access the email via: user.asMap().get("email"));

Comment: user.asMap().get("email")) is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the email like this

```
String email = (String) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("email");
if(email!=null && !email.equals("")
//email variable should've email id.
```

Comment: still getting null, getting all other fields though. unable to track the mistake...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the permission list in the login call.

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(SignUpActivity.this, new LogInCallback() {
//you can add permissions on later screens.
}
```

Comment: can you please explain what you are suggesting?

Comment: Don't include the permission while you login.

Answer (score 0):

Please add you this request:

```
 Request request = Request.newMeRequest(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(),new Request.GraphUserCallback()
```

In login request condition => user.isnew()

```
else if (user.isNew()) {
                Log.w("FB","User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                //showUserDetailsActivity();
                getProfileInfo();
            }
```

write your block in between this and you will be able to get new user info with email also.

This perfectly works in iOS and sure will help in android.

Answer (score 0):

Before the line

```
request.executeAsync();
```

add these three lines.

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
request.setParameters(parameters);
```

Now you will get email in your response